# Flutter SHA1 Invalid Keystore Format Error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, mobile, build

Hi I'm Flutter developer. I try Firebase Google Authentication but I need SHA1 Key. I'm writing this code console in android folder to my project

I'm not using Emulator Device. I'm using Real Device with USB Debugging for Flutter

```
.\gradlew signingReport
```

But i can't get SHA1 Code I have Invalid keystore format error

```
Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\mehme\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\mehme\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

I try delete .android files and re-build project but not resolved

I cant solve this problem.
What should i do to solve this error ?